# Validation of a couple of model classes using FluentValidator

Tags: c#, .net, validation, inheritance

A couple of model classes are doing the validation using `FluentValidator`. These model classes are used to **Add** and **Edit** the branch data and they are working well but I have no idea how to remove the code smell (duplication).

**Problem:** Notice the duplicate validations being written in BranchEditModel class as well. I have marked in the code itself what I think is being duplicated I thought it would be easier for you to read it.

#### BranchAddModel

```
using FluentValidation;
using FluentValidation.Attributes;

namespace Application //sample namespace
{
    [Validator(typeof(BranchAddModelValidator))]
    public class BranchAddModel
    {
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public byte ServiceTypeId { get; set; }
        public short TimezoneId { get; set; }
    }

    public class BranchAddModelValidator : AbstractValidator<BranchAddModel>
    {
        public BranchAddModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.BranchName)
                .NotEmpty()
                .Length(0, 128);  //up to 128 length of string is allowed.

            RuleFor(x => x.ServiceTypeId)
                .NotEmpty();  //mandatory

            RuleFor(x => x.TimezoneId)
                .NotEmpty();  //mandatory
        }
    }
}
```

#### BranchEditModel

*BranchEditModel is inheriting the model from BranchAddModel. And, it has 2 extra properties.*

```
namespace Application //sample namespace
{
    [Validator(typeof(BranchEditModelValidator))]
    public sealed class BranchEditModel : BranchAddModel
    {
        public int BranchId { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

    public class BranchEditModelValidator: AbstractValidator<BranchEditModel>
    {
        public BranchEditModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.BranchName) // code repeated
                .NotEmpty()
                .Length(0, 128);

            RuleFor(x => x.ServiceTypeId) // code repeated
                .NotEmpty();  

            RuleFor(x => x.TimezoneId) // code repeated
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.BranchId) 
                .NotEmpty();

            RuleFor(x => x.IsActive)
                .NotEmpty();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I see two possibilities here.

**1. Use extension methods**

You can define a static class `BranchModelValidationRules` with extension methods for `AbstractValidator<T>` with methods like this:

```
public static void ValidateBranchName<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator)
    where T : BranchAddModel
{
    validator.RuleFor(x => x.BranchName)
        .NotEmpty()
        .Length(0, 128);
}
```

**2. Extract a common base class**

Create a class `BranchModelValidatorBase`:

```
public abstract class BranchModelValidatorBase<T> : AbstractValidator<T> 
    where T : BranchAddModel
{
    public BranchModelValidatorBase()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.BranchName)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(0, 128);  //up to 128 length of string is allowed.

        RuleFor(x => x.ServiceTypeId)
            .NotEmpty();  //mandatory

        RuleFor(x => x.TimezoneId)
            .NotEmpty();  //mandatory
    }
}
```

Create concrete validators by extending the base class:

```
public class BranchAddModelValidator
    : BranchModelValidatorBase<BranchAddModel> 
{
    public BranchAddModelValidator()
    {
        // Create future add-specific rules here.
    }
}

public class BranchEditModelValidator
    : BranchModelValidatorBase<BranchEditModel> 
{
    public BranchEditModelValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.BranchId) 
            .NotEmpty();

        RuleFor(x => x.IsActive)
            .NotEmpty();
    }
}
```

### Update

Regarding your comment about a more generic `Name` property: define an interface, for example like this:

```
public interface IModelWithName
{
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

A matching extension method class might then look like this:

```
public static class ModelValidationRules
{
    public static void ValidateModelName<T>(this AbstractValidator<T> validator)
        where T : IModelWithName
    {
        validator.RuleFor(x => x.Name)
            .NotEmpty()
            .Length(0, 128);
    }
}
```

You can then reuse this method in any validator class that validates models implementing the interface. Alternatively you could create a validator for `IModelWithName` with just a single rule. Then use a matching set of validators for actual model validation.

Comment: I was thinking to extract out the BranchName into more Generic like `NameField` so this could be used in other Model Classes too. Not sure whether this make sense? I don't know how to implement.

Comment: Use an interface. See my updated answer for details.

Comment: Using `Interface` may help but not sure how to link up the `ModelValidationRules` with Concrete Class (eg: BranchAddModel). It's not possible to Add the `Validator` attribute to the concrete class.

Comment: You still have do define a validator class that extends for example `AbstractValidator<BranchAddModel>`. In the constructor of said class you can then add the validation rule with `this.ValidateModelName();`, e.g. replace your current `RuleFor(...)` statement with it.